# dynamic animationextender in a server Table

Tags: asp.net-ajax

im working with asp.net 2.0 (c#).

i have a server HTMLTable bounded with information. i would like to integrate a dynamic  likbutton with related ajax animationExtender in each cellule of My table.

can anynady help me. ( i need some usefull code if possible).

Sincerly Youness.

Answer (score 0):

function linkPostback() {

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm.add_endRequest(playAnimation)
```

}

function playAnimation() {

```
AnimationExtender.Enabled = true;
var onclkBehavior = $find("ctl00_btnOpenList").get_OnClickBehavior().get_animation();
onclkBehavior.play();
AnimationExtender.Enabled = false;
```

}